# Idiomatic way to convert an InputStream to a String in Scala

Tags: string, scala, inputstream

I have a handy function that I've used in Java for converting an InputStream to a String.  Here is a direct translation to Scala:

```
  def inputStreamToString(is: InputStream) = {
    val rd: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")) 
    val builder = new StringBuilder()    
    try {
      var line = rd.readLine 
      while (line != null) { 
        builder.append(line + "\n")
        line = rd.readLine
      }
    } finally {
      rd.close
    }
    builder.toString
  }
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this in scala?

Answer (score 214, accepted):

For Scala >= 2.11

```
scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString
```

For Scala < 2.11:

```
scala.io.Source.fromInputStream(is).getLines().mkString("\n")
```

does pretty much the same thing.  Not sure why you want to get lines and then glue them all back together, though.  If you can assume the stream's nonblocking, you could just use `.available`, read the whole thing into a byte array, and create a string from that directly.

Comment: One possible reason, that I've used myself, is to normalize line endings on different operating systems.

Comment: Raam's answer is also awesome (and slightly more concise), but marking Rex's as THE answer, because it's more specifically like the example.  Glueing the lines back together was specific a few cases, but you reminded me that I've used this code in places where it isn't quite appropriate to do that.

Comment: the solution is not very safe as it uses getLines(); what if the input stream has no "new line" characters? then the whole thing blocks

Comment: Quite a bad solution. What if the inputstream contains DOS line-endings (\r\n). These would be removed by this method. Also, although mkString uses a buffer, it most certainly would be faster to read blocks of characters.

Comment: @Dibbeke - It's the same output the OP said they wanted, even if it's not completely faithful.  Anyway, there's a better option now, which I've added.

Comment: @RexKerr Can you please point out the "performance bug" that you mentioned in your answer. I tested both versions with some basic testcases and didn't hit any issue.

Answer (score 75):

`Source.fromInputStream(is).mkString("")` 
will also do the deed.....

Comment: Good point; source creates something that extends `Iterator[Char]`.

Comment: It's generally good practice to also specify the character encoding when doing this sort of thing.  To that end: 

`Source.fromInputStream(is)(Codec.UTF8).mkString`

Comment: This is terse, but it doesn't close the stream, whereas the original java code did.

Comment: @Rich, `fromInputStream()` appears to close the stream, at least in Scala 2.11.

Comment: @jaco0646 -- it does not close the stream. I just tested. Here is demo code that proves it: https://gist.github.com/RichardBradley/bcd1a5e61fcc83e4e59f8b9b0bc2301c

Comment: @Rich, you're right. I looked again at the method implementation. It is wrapping the `close()` method of the `InputStream` within the `close()` method of the `BufferedSource` so that closing the source closes the stream. It is still the responsibility of the client to close the source.

Answer (score 16):

Faster way to do this:

```
    private def inputStreamToString(is: InputStream) = {
        val inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(is)
        val bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader)
        Iterator continually bufferedReader.readLine takeWhile (_ != null) mkString
    }
```

Comment: "faster"? But it provided me the answer for how to do it when I just have a `Reader` and not an `InputStream`.

Comment: Just skip the first line, and pass `inputStreamReader` to method.

Comment: This is potentially an order of magnitude faster than scala.io.Source in Scala 2.11.7. I wrote a really basic benchmark of it and most of the time, it was about 5% faster for large files (test was ~35 MB text file) all the way up to 2,800% faster for small files (test was ~30 KB).

Comment: Beautiful. Been struggling for an elegant solution reading large inputs from   `Runtime.exec()`. This nails it.

Comment: How would I specify a character set to use?

Comment: Years later, I found a bug in this: it trashes the line ending markers, `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`.