# Read All Lines of BufferedReader in Scala into a String

Tags: scala, bufferedreader

How can I read **all** of a `BufferedReader`'s lines and store into a String?

```
 val br = new BufferedReader(...)
 val str: String = getAllLines(br) // getAllLines() -- is where I need help
```

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221524/idiomatic-way-to-convert-an-inputstream-to-a-string-in-scala).

Comment: Do you have to use `BufferedReader`? Why not `Source.fromFile("myfile.txt").getLines()` or similar?

Comment: I need to use a `BufferedReader` since I'm making use of the `UnicodeBOMInputStream` from here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835430/byte-order-mark-screws-up-file-reading-in-java.

Comment: Then perhaps `Source.fromInputStream(myUnicodeBOMInputStream).getLines()` would be easier.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is how I deal with a `BufferedReader` in Scala:

```
val br:BufferedReader = ???
val strs = Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null)
```

You will have a string for each line from the reader.  If you want it in one single string:

```
val str = Stream.continually(br.readLine()).takeWhile(_ != null).mkString("\n")
```

Comment: The use of `continually` is brilliant. I didn't know it yet. Thanks!

Comment: I recommend simply calling `BufferedReader.close()` per the [Java API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#close()).  Just be sure to call it after you have consumed the data because `Stream` is lazy.  The suggestion to use `mkString("\n")` will force the evaluation of the `Stream` for instance, as will `force`.  But if you were to call `close()` after the `val strs = ...` line, you will not be able to read any lines.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using `null` in your solution?

Comment: @kfkhalili, one approach would be:
`val str = Stream.continually(reader.readLine()).takeWhile(Option(_).nonEmpty).mkString("\n")`