# Scala: read user input as single string

Tags: scala

I need get all user input in stdin as single string in scala 2.12 (supposed the data would copy-pasted by single action), something like this:

```
please copy data:
word1
word2
word3
```

And I need get string with following data:

```
val str = "word1\nword2\nword3"
```

my current approach is not working, just hanging forever:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val scanner: Iterator[String] = new Scanner(System.in).asScala

val sb = new StringBuilder
while (scanner.hasNext) {
  sb.append(scanner.next())
}
val str = sb.toString()
```

Although this can print the input:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConverters._
val scanner: Iterator[String] = new Scanner(System.in).asScala

scanner foreach println
```

I'm looking for idiomatic way of doing the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
LazyList
  .continually(StdIn.readLine())
  .takeWhile(_ != null)
  .mkString("\n")
```

as inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/18924749/5205022

On my machine I could terminate the input with `^D`.

In Scala 2.12 replace `LazyList` with `Stream`.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work for me properly. Btw what is LazyList? I used Iterator.continually instead but it is hanging forever unless I introduced special ending character

Comment: ohh I realised it is a new collection from scala 2.13, does it make difference vs Iterator ?

Comment: @Normal In Scala 2.12, just replace `LazyList` with `Stream`. In what way is it not working properly, that is, what error are you getting?